# How can I break SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

That is to say -- What can I do to generate a correlation ID?

**The reason...**

I have a console application snippet that apparently allows you to pull out the error info from SPO using the error correlation ID. However, I have recently read that it no longer works. I want to test this for myself but I don't know what I can do inside SPO that would break and generate an ID for me.

If I could deploy managed code I could spin something up, but I'm restricted to JSOM, or perhaps misconfiguring something through the UI that would cause an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related to your question, but where did you find the snippet? That sounds like a very useful utility!

Comment: I'm using this guide: http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/view-tenant-uls-logs-in-sharepoint.html

Comment: haha clickbait question :) 531 views already :)

Comment: Not my intention! Hard to succinctly phrase it any other way. Any Microsoft SharePoint employee's hearts will skip a beat if they see that the questions not only exists, but is also marked as answered!

Comment: @RayHogan I am author of the post you are referring to and I can confirm  the TenantLog API does not work. The Microsoft Engineering team confirmed that in one of the YamJams on the Office 365 Technical network. I will try to dig up the link for you. It's a shame the classes exist in CSOM but there is no server side implementation for them.

Comment: What a pity! Thanks for letting me know, Vardhaman.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a) create a test page, e.g. "test.aspx" in SharePoint Designer

b) add a reference to a non existing control

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MyControls" TagName="SuperControl" Src="~/_controltemplates/SuperControl.ascx" %>
```

c) load up test.aspx anytime to generate a new correlation id

**Result**

Sorry, something went wrong

File Not Found.

TECHNICAL DETAILS

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 286d719d-404b-2000-09cd-c18818b2fd05

Date and Time: 4/11/2016 2:27:27 AM

Comment: `2:27:27 AM`.  Looks like you're up late solving SharePoint issues..err..breaking SharePoint in this case I suppose.

Comment: This is awkward. My tenant is in Europe/Dublin, but I am apparently getting East Coast time. changing regional settings didn't help. Oh well...

Comment: Yeah unfortunately Office 365 internal times are reported for Microsoft's convenience ;)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following scenario:

1. You open the Solution Gallery in the Solutions area of Site Settings in Microsoft SharePoint Online.
2. You change the Require content approval for submitted items? setting to Yes.
3. When you try to save the site as a template, you receive the following error message:

> Sorry, something went wrong
>
> An unexpected error has occurred.

Comment: Thanks, just tested this and it worked. I have an ID I can play with. Cheers!